# How to draw from web app to android app screen in real time

Tags: android, html, canvas

How to draw from web app to android app screen in real time?

is there any way to communicate web app to android app in real time?

i want to draw from web app to android app screen in real time?

**How can i communicate from browser to android app in real time?**

**If i get the (x,y) position from web page, how can i send it to android app and told it to draw on its screen(any transparent layer/canvas)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can communicate Via `web services` at real time from *web application* to an *android application*.

You can set the `web service` code to send data from *web* To *android application*, suppose on button click.

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 0):

Use web sockets to communicate in real time.

> SERVER:

This exposes a web socket. Can be a simple Node.js server. [Refer this](https://www.js-tutorials.com/nodejs-tutorial/simple-websocket-example-with-nodejs/)

> WEB APP

A simple web application that connects to the above web socket. Refer in the same link where they will guide you to create a client.js which is the client part of the app

> ANDROID APP

[Refer this article](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/java-websocket-programming-with-android-and-spring-boot/) which explains the simple way to connect & listen to web socket

> APPROACH

When you draw something on the webpage (assuming you do it on a canvas), just get the coordinates of the drawing & send it to server thru web sockets. You can decide on when to send data using onMouseMove, onTouchEnd.....you get the idea

And on the other target side, you listen to messages coming thru web socket connection & then you handle it.

Note:
If you want really fast comm between the connected clients then look into the world of WEBRTC where you will use the SERVER only for initial handshake & later use direct peer to peer connection for all ongoing messages which can include video, audio calls, screen sharing